# Oscilloscope app using mpandroidchart

Tags: mpandroidchart

I'm trying to create an app that can display linegraphs at a sample rate of 15 kHz frequency and have run into two main problems: 
I cant seem to set the sample rate to anywhere below 1 ms(I'm using thread.sleep(1) to set the time duration between each value.
Also the graph shows too little onscreen at any given time. I've set xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels to 1 and still am only getting about 6 entries on screen at any given time. Is it at all possible to get a higher sample rate(at the order of nanoseconds) and get the chart to display much higher number of entries on screen?

Currently the app displays random values as the entries. This is the code snippet:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //real time addition

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //adding 100 entries
            for ( int i = 0;i<3000; i++) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        addEntry();
                    }
                });

                //pausing between each addition
                //pausing between each addition
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(600);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    // to manage error....
                }


            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

EDIT: Figured out how to show more entries onscreen (setVisibleXRange) but still have the problem of increasing samplerate.

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase sampling rate just use TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep instead of Thread.sleep.
Also don't forget to import TimeUnit library(alt enter doesnt work) ;)

Thanks for all the help.